# Word template on sharepoint does not open new document

Tags: document, word, template, ie

on our sharepoint we plan to replace our existing word documents with word templates. Most of the people use Internet Explorer 11, some use Chrome and some added the address as a network path to their wondows explorer.

When I try to open a template with sharepoint on IE it opens the template itself and not a new document. With Chrome the template gets downloaded and has to be opend again, which is also not a good sulution. Is there a way so that the template always opens a new document? This would be important since there are macros used in the document wich only work when a new document gets created.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Which version of Sharepoint, and what does the link to the "new document based on the template" look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted same type of question in this forum see below link i tried the url to open document,

[Open existing word document in Client Application as a new document](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265903/open-existing-word-document-in-client-application-as-a-new-document)